# Stuck at "Started Show Plymouth Reboot Screen" during reboot

Tags: boot-issues

I installed Raspbian Jessie LITE in Raspberry Pi 3 (which I just purchased) by writing the image file to an 64GB microSD card.

The OS booted up just fine, and I'm able to login to make changes (change password, keyboard layout, connect to wifi, etc). But after I reboot, the booting sequence is always stuck at:

> Started Show Plymouth Reboot Screen

How can I resolve it?

p.s. I just changed the keyboard layout to US (as I cannot type certain characters & some keys are swapped in default keyboard layout) via `raspi-config` and extend the filesystem. The tool requested me to reboot when I try to quit the tool, then I select "Yes"... and end up stuck with the above message

p.s. When I press F2, Esc, Left / Right button, there is a mysterious grey screen appeared and showed 3 square dots. What is it?